# How do I plot an abline() when I don't have any data points (in R)

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have to plot a few different simple linear models on a chart, the main point being to comment on them. I have no data for the models. I can't get R to create a plot with appropriate axes, i.e. I can't get the range of the axes correct. I think I'd like my y-axis to 0-400 and x to be 0-50.
Models are:
$$
\widehat y=108+0.20x_1
$$$$
\widehat y=101+2.15x_1
$$$$
\widehat y=132+0.20x_1
$$$$
\widehat y=119+8.15x_1
$$
I know I could possibly do this much more easily in a different software or create a dataset from the model and estimate and plot the model from that but I'd love to know if there is a better way in R.

Comment: The `type=n` argument to `plot` will let you do a plot with no points shown, and `ylim` and `xlim` let you specify the limits. See `?plot.default` for details. `?abline` contains examples of drawing lines after that. The third call there is an example of what you need.

Answer (score 2):

As *@Glen_b* noticed, `type = "n"` in plot produces a plot with nothing on it. As it demands data, you have to provide *anything* as `x` - it can be `NA`, or some data. If you provide actual data, the `plot` function will figure out the plot margins from the data, otherwise you have to choose the margins by hand using `xlim` and `ylim` arguments. Next, you use `abline` that has parameters `a` and `b` for intercept and slope (or `h` and `v` if you want just a horizontal or vertical line).

```
plot(x=NA, type="n", ylim=c(100, 250), xlim=c(0, 50),
     xlab=expression(x[1]), ylab=expression(hat(y)))
abline(a=108, b=0.2, col="red")
abline(a=101, b=2.15, col="green")
abline(a=132, b=0.2, col="blue")
abline(a=119, b=8.15, col="orange")
```